Как скрыть строку состояния и навигационные кнопки
Есть проект, написанный на Kotlin Jetpack Compose, сейчас в программе постоянно отображается строка состояния (время, заряд батареи и тд) и навигационные кнопки (Три кнопки: кнопка Назад, Меню..). Как сделать так, чтобы строка и кнопки исчезли, и появлялись только после проведения пальцами в той области?
Main Activity
package com.example.dateditor2.ui

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.activity.viewModels
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material3.Scaffold
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import com.example.dateditor2.ui.theme.DatEditor2Theme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private val viewModel by viewModels<MainViewModel>()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            DatEditor2Theme {
                Scaffold {
                    Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(it)) {
                        NavGraph(viewModel)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Manifest:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.DatEditor2"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="reverseLandscape"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.DatEditor2">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

